# Revoke saml token

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, revoke-token

Can we revoke saml token in azure aad .i got to see revoking refresh tokens documentations but i never saw any document for revoking saml token.is there any possibility to revoke saml token from azure AAD ?

Comment: Could you include more details like what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism for revocation in Azure (or most SAML implementations). Each SAML token has a [configurable lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-saml-tokens) defined by `NotBefore` and `NotOnOrAfter`. The default in AAD is a one-hour lifetime.

Azure also supports [Single Sign-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol).

These are the only mechanisms built into Azure. You could might be able to get better controls with some of the APIs, but this is what you get out of the box.